# Как получить json через post в slim и добавить в базу данных?

Tags: php, mysql, json, api, slim

Необходимо получить **post** запрос в формате **json** и записать в базу данных. Но в итоге в `$id` при выводе либо `null` либо ничего.

Использую **SLIM 3**.

Я отправляю через `postman` такой запрос:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя попытка это провернуть:

```
    global $mysql;
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    $id = $request->getParsedBody();
    print_r($id);
   
    $query = "INSERT INTO tete(du, name, price) VALUES ({$id[du]},{$id[name]},{$id[price]})";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($mysql, $query)) {
        echo "Все круто";
    } else {
        echo "Все плохо";
    }
});
```

Comment: Что со скобками то? `VALUES ($id[du]},$id[name]}`

Comment: Наверное пробовал с ними и без них и забыл убрать или добавить...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по скрину, вы отправляете в теле не валидный json (запятая после последнего элемента запрещена). Слим не может правильно распарсить, поэтому `getParsedBody()` возвращает `null`